# Moq framework Func<T,T>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am new with Moq and TDD and what I am trying to do is to set up method on repository interface.

Here is full story.

I have a domain entity class called Tenant with property BusinessIdentificationNumber

```
public class Tenant:EntityBase<Tenant>,IAggregateRoot
{
 ...
 public string BusinessIdentificationNumber {get;set;}
 ...
}
```

Next I have repository for this entity which interface is like

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
 ...
 T FindBy(Func<T,bool> func);
 ...
}
```

where the problem is, I use a domain service which holds the rules for creating a tenant and is like

```
public class TenantCreationService:ITenantCreationService
{
    public TenantCreationService(IRepository<Tenant> tenantRepository){...}

    public void CreateTenant(Tenant tenant)
    {
        //from here there is call to IRepository<Tenant>.FindBy(funcMethod);
    }
}
```

And in unit testing where I am testing the TenantCreationService I mock the repository passed to constructor, but I would like to test the feature :

- when tenant with BusinessIdentificationNumber already exists in storage or session it should be returned.

So I was trying to do it like

```
repositoryMock.Setup(x=>x.FindBy(It.Is<Tenant>(t=>t.BusinessIdentificationNumber
   == _tenantInTest.BusinessIdentificationNumber))).Returns(_tenantInTest)
```

but it does not compile. You know what I want to do?

EDIT:
when i try to compile the snippet below

```
repositoryMock.Setup(e => e.FindBy(t => t.BusinessNumber == _validTenant.BusinessNumber)).Returns(
                _validTenant);
```

i get exception

```
Unsupported expression: t => (t.BusinessNumber == value(DP.IPagac.UnitTests.DP.IPagac.Module.TenantManagement.TenantDomainServiceTests)._validTenant.BusinessNumber)
```

Comment: can you include the compile error in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are trying the acheive is this (removed some things that were extraneous for example and created ITenent so it can be mocked dynamically):

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void CreateTenentAlreadyExistsTest()
    {
        var tenentMock = new Mock<ITenant>();
        var repoMock = new Mock<IRepository<ITenant>>();

        tenentMock.Setup(t => t.BusinessIdentificationNumber).Returns("aNumber");

        repoMock.Setup(r => r.FindBy(It.Is<System.Func<ITenant, bool>>(func1 => func1.Invoke(tenentMock.Object)))).Returns(tenentMock.Object);

        var tenantCreationService = new TenantCreationService(repoMock.Object);

        tenantCreationService.CreateTenant(tenentMock.Object);

        tenentMock.VerifyAll();
        repoMock.VerifyAll();
    }
}

public interface ITenant
{
    string BusinessIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant : ITenant
{
    public string BusinessIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T FindBy(System.Func<T, bool> func);
}

public class TenantCreationService : ITenantCreationService
{
    private readonly IRepository<ITenant> _tenantRepository;

    public TenantCreationService(IRepository<ITenant> tenantRepository)
    {
        _tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
    }

    public void CreateTenant(ITenant tenant)
    {
        var existingTenant =
            _tenantRepository.FindBy(t => t.BusinessIdentificationNumber == tenant.BusinessIdentificationNumber);

        if (existingTenant == null)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}

public interface ITenantCreationService
{
    void CreateTenant(ITenant tenant);
}
```

Comment: yes, you got it with call on findby method. i think you understand what iam try to do, but your code did not compile on me. I got an unsupported exception t=> (t.BusinessNumber == value). whatiam trying to achieve is that on calling the findby with tenant with specific business number the specific tenant should be returned (for test purspose of course).

Comment: Have you got the latest MOQ? What version of the Framework are you using? The above compiles and passes test on my workstation verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

"when tenant with BusinessIdentificationNumber already exists in storage or session it should be returned." - from this test description I understood that this behavior you should test in repository class not in on service class

In unit test for services you should not test data accesses layer I mean your repositories,
you should just verify that the repository method FindBy was called.
and my suggest Create ITenantRepositry that derive from IRepository interface and from base class Repostiry.

Comment: but this is business behavior hold in service class. i use repository only for fetching data from database. the whole test is called CreateTenant_TenantWithSameIdAlreadyExist_ShouldThrowException() [and the sentence about implementation details is only for dev purpose, doesnt make sense to present you here business r.]; iam not testing the repository behavior but i would like to mock the repository that way that on calling the CreateMethod on service (and it delegates the call to repository) with predefined condition (BusinessID == "123") it should return the tenant created in testfixturesetup