# Moq Setup returning null

Tags: moq

I set up my mock object using Moq like this:

```
var accountRepositoryMock = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Account>>();
accountRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AccountId == It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(new Account { AccountId = 99999999, Valid = true });

var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
unitOfWorkMock.SetupGet(unitofwork => unitofwork.AccountRepository).Returns(accountRepositoryMock.Object);
```

Then I pass it to my service like this:

```
 IQuickPayService quickPayService = new QuickPayService(unitOfWorkMock.Object);
 Account account = quickPayService.ValidateAccount(accountId);
```

When I do this in my client code, I am getting account as null

```
public class QuickPayService : IQuickPayService
{
   public QuickPayService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
   {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
   } 

   public AccountStatus ValidateAccount(long accountId)
   {
        var account;
        using (_unitOfWork)
        {
           account = _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.SingleOrDefault(acc => acc.AccountId == 99999999);

        }
        return account;
   }
```

}

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside, I recommend avoiding generic repository interfaces. See http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/ for an excellent discussion of this.

Comment: @TrueWill I'm not sure I completely agree with your assumptions. Different objects do have different requirements, but perhaps that is best handled in a business logic layer rather than in a repository. After all, making the repository handle the business rules would violate the single responsibility principle, wouldn't it? I have taken the view that the repository implementation lives in the data access layer rather than the business logic layer.

Comment: @TimLong I agree; however, I want my queries in the DAL. See also [IQueryable is Tight Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/). It's the same problem as providing an OData service; it exposes too many details, making it harder to change the repository implementation.

Comment: @TrueWill well this probably is not the right place to have this discussion, but I don't agree with that article either. The author goes on about IQueryable<T> 'putting huge demands on the caller' and that 'the caller must be able to implement the entire interface'. I fail to understand those points, since I can't see how any such demands are placed on the caller, who has neither to implement the interface nor really be concerned about the implementation details. What's clear is that there are different approaches and making blanket statements is probably not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your interface is declared similarly to the following:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T>
{
    T SingleOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

Specifying a delegate in `Setup` won't work. See [Issue 300: Mocking Method with Delegate as Parameter](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=300). I get a `NotSupportedException` when I tried it.

Instead, try this:

```
accountRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.SingleOrDefault(It.IsAny<Func<Account, bool>>()))
    .Returns(new Account { AccountId = 99999999, Valid = true });
```

There's a more detailed example at [Moq framework Func<T,T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228164/moq-framework-funct-t/9228556#9228556)

Comment: My interface definition looks like this    
    `T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);` 
so I had to do this 
     `accountRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.SingleOrDefault(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Account, bool>>>())).Returns(new Account{ AccountId = 99999999, Valid = true });`